# Python Multiprocessing shared variables erratic behavior

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

The following simple code should, as far I can see, always print out '0' in the end. However, when running it with "lock = True", it often prints out other positive or negative numbers.

```
  import multiprocessing as mp
  import sys
  import time

  num = mp.Value('d', 0.0, lock = False)


  def func1():
      global num
      print ('start func1')
      #While num.value < 100000:
      for x in range(1000):
          num.value += 1
          #print(num.value)
      print ('end func1')

  def func2():
      global num
      print ('start func2')
      #while num.value > -10000:
      for x in range(1000):
          num.value -= 1
          #print(num.value)
      print ('end func2')

if __name__=='__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('fork')
    p1 =  ctx.Process(target=func1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = ctx.Process(target=func2)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(25)
    print(num.value)
```

Can anyone offer any explanation?

To clarify: When lock is set to "False", it behaves as expected, printing out '0', however, when it is "True" it often does not.

This is more noticeable/happens more often for larger values of 'range'.

Tested this on two platforms (Mac OSx and Ubuntu 14.04.01) both with python 3.6.

Comment: What version of python, platform did you used? Both cases behave as expected: https://ideone.com/JoBXwZ

Comment: This is the output from the link you posted: start func2
end func2
start func1
end func1
124.0

Should the final number not be 0? How is this expected?

Comment: I've run it about 10 times, and always got 0.0 at the end. We must live in a parallel universe. :D

Comment: Haha, try increasing the range!

Comment: The link from the first time you ran it had 124.0, I'm sure, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) for `multiprocessing.Value` are very explicit about this:

> Operations like += which involve a read and write are not atomic. So if, for instance, you want to atomically increment a shared value it is insufficient to just do
>
> ```
> counter.value += 1
> ```
>
> Assuming the associated lock is recursive (which it is by default) you can instead do
>
> ```
> with counter.get_lock():
>     counter.value += 1
> ```

To your comment, this is not "1000 incrementations". This is 1000 iterations of:

```
# Take lock on num.value
temp_value = num.value    # (1)
# release lock on num.value (anything can modify it now)
temp_value += 1           # (2)
# Take lock on num.value
num.value = temp_value    # (3)
# release lock on num.value
```

That's what it means when it says `+=` is not atomic.

If `num.value` is modified by another process during line 2, then line 3 will write the wrong value to `num.value`.

---

To give an example of a better way to approach what you're doing, here's a version using Queues that ensures everything stays tick-tock in lock step:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
import sys


# An increment process. Takes a value, increments it, passes it along
def func1(in_queue: mp.Queue, out_queue: mp.Queue):
    print('start func1')

    for x in range(1000):
        n = in_queue.get()
        n += 1
        print("inc", n)
        out_queue.put(n)
    print('end func1')


# An decrement process. Takes a value, decrements it, passes it along
def func2(in_queue: mp.Queue, out_queue: mp.Queue):
    print('start func2')
    for x in range(1000):
        n = in_queue.get()
        n -= 1
        print("dec", n)
        out_queue.put(n)
    print('end func2')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('fork')

    queue1 = mp.Queue()
    queue2 = mp.Queue()

    # Make two processes and tie their queues back to back. They hand a value
    # back and forth until they've run their course.
    p1 = ctx.Process(target=func1, args=(queue1, queue2,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = ctx.Process(target=func2, args=(queue2, queue1,))
    p2.start()

    # Get it started
    queue1.put(0)

    # Wait from them to finish
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    # Since this is a looping process, the result is on the queue we put() to.
    # (Using block=False because I'd rather throw an exception if something
    # went wrong rather than deadlock.)
    num = queue1.get(block=False)

    print("FINAL=%d" % num)
```

This is a very simplistic example. In more robust code you need to think about what happens in failure cases. For example, if `p1` throws an exception, `p2` will deadlock waiting for its value. In many ways that's a good thing since it means you can recover the system by starting a new `p1` process with the same queues. This way of dealing with concurrency is called the [Actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) if you want to study it further.

Comment: Well, yes, but, should it still not be the case that in the end, after 1000 incrementations, and 1000 decrementations, we are back at 0 regardless of that?

Comment: Plus, this only happens when the argument  'lock = true' not when 'lock = false' which makes no sense to me.

Comment: You're likely just getting lucky when `lock=False` because the operations are much faster (there's no "take a lock" step). The race condition still exists; you're just not seeing it because it is dramatically smaller. Taking a lock is a very slow operation. It is also possible that the shared memory on your platform allows an atomic increment that += is implemented with when there's no lock (I'd have to study the source to see if they're using this). Even if true, that would be very dangerous to rely on.

Comment: Ah, makes sense, thanks! Another questions: if I use the while loop which is commented out in the code (without the for loop) and set the locks correctly, should it not run forever?

Comment: There's no promise of that. It totally depends on what order the operations run in. There's no promise that each process will get the same amount of time. One process could run until complete and then the other process could start and that would meet all the promises of the system. (Unless by "set the locks correctly" you mean "add a synchronization point that blocks each process until the other process does one of its iterations." Don't confuse concurrency w/ parallelism: https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I'm not entirely sure about how to do that for the code above, though.

Comment: And even with proper locking so that one iteration is a unit, there is no guarantee that the processes will run alternatively (i.e. one turn for A then one turn for B), is there?

Comment: Sure. The simplest is to use two `Condition` objects. But I'd never build a system this way. Rather than having two processes messing with global state, I would use `Queue` objects to hand the state from one process to another.

Comment: Ah, but I'm trying to use it for asynchronous training with model replicas, where each model updates the graph without locking, leading to faster convergence (hogwild).

Comment: There is no safe, platform-independent way to increment a value across processes without locking. Lockless solutions are going to be platform dependent (they generally rely on a "compare and swap" operation implemented by the CPU). If you're optimizing at this level, I would likely recommend moving into platform-specific C for that portion.